# Problems installing DBAN on a Windows 10 Install USB

Tags: dban

I have created a Windows 10 install USB. I want this USB to also perform other tasks.
Then I used BCDEdit to create a Grub4Dos entry, that in turns boots the following menu:

```
timeout 10
default 0

title MemTest86+
kernel (hd0,0)/memtest.bin
lock

title DBAN
kernel (hd0,0)/dban.bzi
append nuke="dwipe"
lock

title Reboot
reboot

title Shut down
halt
```

The memtest entry does work wonderfully.
However, the DBAN entry, goes through the DBAN boot, and then says it exited due to fatal errors.

It offered the option to store the log. Here is the log (Log too large to put here, so I put it on Pastebin):

https://pastebin.com/6gizhpDG

What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Did you boot in legacy/BIOS mode?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring yes